# Dark gray section in the viewport that can't be changed?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

What is this long dark section? I'm not sure what I did to make it appear but it prevents me from seeing other objects in my scene. I tried adjusting the clipping already but it did not seem to help.

Comment: If the answer helped, please consider accepting it .

Answer (score 0):

It's called the clipping Border and gets created or disabled with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: @joe Not for very much longer. .